# Erro when trying to deploy fat Jar on Heroku

Tags: heroku, heroku-api

I'm trying to deploy a Fat Jar on heroku, and heroku keeps give me following erro code. It looks like that I have got the Path wrong, but after I double checked it, It should be correckt [position of my Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r3rHg.png)  [My commands and erro code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LxZDM.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're in a different directory in your terminal than you are in the File Explorer. From your terminal, you can run `dir` to get a list of all files in the current directory. You want to upload the file `Testbot.jar`, but it's actually at `out/artifacts/Testbot_jar/Testbot.jar`.

In your terminal, run

```
cd Testbot_jar
```

and then run

```
dir
```

and you should see the file there.

```
Volume in drive C has no label.
Volume Serial Number is B86A-EF32

Directory of C:\Users\Dingda\IdeaProjects\Testbot\out\artifacts\Testbot_jar

03/22/2021  01:40 PM <DIR>  .
03/22/2021  01:40 PM <DIR> ..
03/22/2021  11:05 AM 123 Testbot.jar
```

Double-check that you can see `Testbot.jar` and then run your command again and you should be good to go.

Comment: Glad that helped! If you found it helpful, please consider [upvoting/accepting the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).